# Как вставлять куски кода в textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

Хочу реализовать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку вставлялась область для кода в textarea, а именно туда, где сейчас стоит курсор. И чтобы в этой области можно было код писать. Читал про `Codemirror`, но не нашёл нормально работающего примера с ним. Может быть найдутся предложения как сделать или примеры какие? Скрин на что я примерно ориентируюсь, прикрепляю ниже.

Скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если я потом сохраняю в бд содержимое textarea, то как эти области с кодом сохранятся?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вставляете код.

```js
const code = `foo += 1;
console.log(foo);`;

function insert() {
    const textArea = document.getElementById('textArea');
    const cursorPosition = textArea.selectionStart;
    const result = textArea.value.substring(0, cursorPosition) + code + textArea.value.substring(cursorPosition);
    textArea.value = result;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textArea" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
const foo = 1;

const boo = 2;
</textarea>
<button onClick="insert()">вставить код</button>
```

А в БД сохранится то, что вы туда сохраните.